# libpcap file header c++

Tags: c++, header, global, libpcap

How do you initialize the pcap_file_header function within libpcap? 
Currently reading in pcap files using pcap_open_offline and extracting the information using the pcap_pkthdr header and data within each packet. Just want to be able to extract the information from the global header? 
Any help/advice greatly appreciated.
//Step 2 - Get a file name
    string file = "/Users/trader/Documents/udp-224.0.31.11_14320.cap";

```
//Step 3 - Create an char array to hold the error.
// Note: errbuf in pcap_open functions is assumed to be able to hold at least PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE chars
// PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE is defined as 256.
char errbuff[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

//Step 4 - Open the file and store result in pointer to pcap_t
//Use pcap_open_offline
pcap_t * pcap = pcap_open_offline(file.c_str(), errbuff);

//Step 5 - Create a header and a data object

// Create a header object:
struct pcap_file_header *globalHeader;
struct pcap_pkthdr *header;
const u_char *data;

//Step 6 - Loop through packets and print them to screen
u_int packetCount = 0;
char sourceIp[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
char destIp[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------");

globalHeader= (struct pcap_file_header*) file.c_str();
printf("\nMagic Number: %x\n", globalHeader->magic);
printf("Major Version Number %x\n", globalHeader->version_major);
printf("Minor Version Number  %x\n", globalHeader->version_minor);
printf("GMT to local correction: %x\n", globalHeader->thiszone);
printf("Accuaracy of Timestamp: %x\n", globalHeader->sigfigs);
printf("Max length of captured packets, in octets: %x\n", globalHeader->snaplen);
printf("Data Link Type  %x\n", globalHeader->linktype);
```

Comment: It's not a function, it's a structure. You simply read from the file into a structure variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, see I'm currently doing it the following way: struct pcap_file_header *globalHeader;globalHeader = (struct pcap_file_header*)file.c_str(); but when I compare the hex output to the packet file it doesn't match. Sorry if i've done something extremely silly/stupid  - new to this.

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit the question.